# Convert toast message datetime from server to local datetime on device

Tags: push-notification, uwp

I'm sending push notification from Azure using custom template to UWP device.  Part of the message contains a date time stamp aa UTC.  On the receiving device I want to intercept the toast message and convert the date time to the user local time zone, before it gets displayed to the user.

Is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no may to change a push notification on client before it showing. You should consider doing this is server side.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to switch to using raw push notifications if you want to execute code locally in response to a push notification. There's no way to include dates that automatically get localized.

Here's documentation on raw push notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-raw-notification-overview

Basically...

1. Your app registers a `PushNotificationTrigger` background task
2. Your app obtains a push channel like normal, sends it up to your server
3. Your server sends a raw push notification to your device containing the raw message data you want to display
4. Your app's background task wakes up, processes the raw message data, and then locally creates and sends a toast notification from it

That allows you to generate the toast notification locally, correctly localizing the date and anything else.

Ideally, your raw push notification would actually just be a "shoulder tap" that says "there's something new, ask the server what's new" rather than sending the actual content in the raw notification itself, since raw notifications are NOT queued up... if your server sends multiple raws and your device was offline, when it comes back on, it will only receive at most one raw, so you would miss the content in your previous raws. Hence if in your background task you simply go back and ask your server "What's new", you won't miss displaying any content.